# Google cloud app engine pinging my server despite disabling health check

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a rails app on the google cloud app engine, and I keep getting pings like this every second or so:

```
19:23:59.883 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health
19:23:58.944 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:58.700 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:57.317 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:57.300 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:56.961 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:54.883 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:53.943 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:53.699 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:52.317 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:52.299 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:51.961 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health 
19:23:49.882 200 2 B 0 ms GET GoogleHC/1.0 /_ah/vm_health
```

I've disabled the health check in my app.yaml

```
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
```

How do I stop these checks? I am worried I am being charged for the traffic

Comment: Have you tried deleting all the params except: `enable_health_check: False`?  I assume you've deployed since the changes.

Comment: @GAEfan just tried and re-deployed, but still getting pinged constantly

Comment: Try going to cloud console, and seeing which instance this is running in.  Shut down that instance.  Have you deployed any other backend modules where this could be running?

Comment: I only see the option to delete an instance in the app engine > instances page for my project. I only have this active project on GAE if that is what you mean.

Comment: Did you get an answer on this? We're running into the same issue with a single instance of the default service and "enable_health_check: False". This is annoying!

Comment: @PlusInfinite actually wound up going with heroku!

Answer (score 1):

So, seems that the URL `/_ah/vm_health` is returning a 503, and retrying.  Can you get that URL to return a 200?  That should stop the loop.

Comment: It still is checking very often with the 200, every second or so.